# How do I remove this Elder Scroll from my inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the quest [Discerning the Transmundane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane) I received an Elder Scroll.

This is great and all, and who doesn't want to own an Elder Scroll, but the problem is that it weighs 20 (pounds? kilos? I'm not sure) and is marked as a quest item, causing me to be unable to store it in a chest etc.

Is there a way to make it unmarked as a quest item, giving me the ability to keep it but store it away? If not, is there a way to get rid of it without using the console (I'll use the console if I have to, but I'd rather not).

Comment: you want to give away an Elder Scroll?! I'd keep it and look if I need it again in the future, maybe in the main questline _broad hint_

Comment: @ordag I want to keep it. But a weight of 20 is a bit much.

Comment: All of these answers are true. I believe they fixed the quest items in the patch, making them weigh nothing. But if you're like me and like to keep your inventory clean, then yes, you can sell it to the guy at the college.

Comment: Quest items have always weighed nothing; I tested this pre-1.2 when Alto Wine became a quest item for me and I was worried that it was using up all my carrying capacity.  :-)

Comment: Not to ruin it for you, but you need that elder scroll to complete on of the main line quests, i would hold onto it so you don't have to hunt another one down.

Comment: keep it!!!! you may not need it again but weighs nothing, so keep it around for braging rights. it's worth way more than 2000G!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the wiki you linked:

> The Elder Scroll can be sold to Urag gro-Shub in the College of Winterhold's Arcanaeum for 2000 gold.

You don't get to keep it, but at least you don't have to carry it around everywhere.

Comment: Haha, I thought I read that page fully, guess not.

Comment: Do you only need to keep the Elder Scroll until you get Dragonrend, or do you need it for the trapping in Dragonsreach?

Comment: The only time I've used it is to get Dragonrend; it doesn't seem to be needed through the rest of the main questline.

Comment: I heard you can also give it ti the moth priest for 600 gold too.

Comment: Well, in Dawnguard.

Answer (score 32):

Any item marked as Quest Items actually weighs nothing at all (even when it has a weight displayed), so there is no need for you to give it away.

Comment: The elder scroll actually weights 40 IIRC. (at least not 0)

Comment: @M'vy Actually I just did some testing, dropped everything in my inventory except my quest items, and I had a net weight of 0, even though I had the elder scroll in my inventory, so alexander is correct.

Comment: I did a Thalmor Embasy style strip down for the Gourmet mission. Had all three scrolls in my inventory. Final weight was 35.

Answer (score 1):

You can sell it to the orc guy in the Winterhold College library like I did, but I don't know if you need it again.  Selling it gets you 2000 gold.

Answer (score -2):

You can't actually.

I tried to sell the elder scroll but when I went to the items I had it did not show up.

Comment: This is happening to me also.